# Не удается проверить GPG подпись файла

Tags: безопасность, шифрование, gpg

Добрый день!
На сайте https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/ есть описание как проверить загружаемый с него файл при помощи GPG подписи:

```
$ curl -O https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp
...
$ curl -O https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp.asc
...
$ gpg --verify quicklisp.lisp.asc quicklisp.lisp
gpg: Signature made Sat Feb  1 09:25:28 2014 EST using RSA key ID 028B5FF7
gpg: Good signature from "Quicklisp Release Signing Key "
```

Я выполняю то-же самое, но у меня ответ другой:

```
$ gpg --verify quicklisp.lisp.asc quicklisp.lisp
gpg: Подпись сделана Чт 29 янв 2015 05:13:26 +08
gpg:                ключом RSA с идентификатором 307965AB028B5FF7
gpg: Не могу проверить подпись: Нет открытого ключа
```

Выяснил - нужно импортировать открытый ключ. Нашел там-же: https://beta.quicklisp.org/release-key.txt. Импортировал... Оно снова матерится, еще страшнее:

```
$ gpg --verify quicklisp.lisp.asc quicklisp.lisp
gpg: Подпись сделана Чт 29 янв 2015 05:13:26 +08
gpg: ключом RSA с идентификатором 307965AB028B5FF7
gpg: Действительная подпись пользователя "Quicklisp Release Signing Key <release@quicklisp.org>" [неизвестно]
gpg: Внимание: Данный ключ не заверен доверенной подписью!
gpg: Нет указаний на то, что подпись принадлежит владельцу.
Отпечаток первичного ключа: D7A3 489D DEFE 32B7 D0E7  CC61 3079 65AB 028B 5FF7
```

Почему так происходит? Может я что-то делаю не так, или что-то не сделал для того, чтобы получить валидный ответ? Зачем тут подпись?

Comment: Это может означать, что нужен CA сертификат, которым подписан открытый ключ?

Comment: CA - это типа корневого? А где его искать чтобы проверить подпись? Это как-то связано с американскими ограничениями на экспорт крипто-технологий?

Comment: хотя вряд-ли. Адрес сайта - 198.100.148.110, находится в Канаде.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> gpg: Действительная подпись пользователя "Quicklisp Release Signing Key <release@quicklisp.org>" [неизвестно]
> gpg: Внимание: Данный ключ не заверен доверенной подписью!
> gpg: Нет указаний на то, что подпись принадлежит владельцу.
> ```
>
> Почему так происходит?

оригинальное сообщения звучит так (ну, просто для справки):

```
gpg: Good signature from "Quicklisp Release Signing Key <release@quicklisp.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
```

означает оно, что файл **действительно** подписан ключом `Quicklisp Release Signing Key <release@quicklisp.org>`, но этот ключ не входит в число ключей, которым **вы** доверяете. не более того.

ответ на вопрос о том, каким образом ключ может стать *доверенным*, несколько не укладывается в рамки *so* (ну, помимо «вредного совета» взять да и назначить его доверенным). рекомендуемое чтение:

- [The GNU Privacy Handbook](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html) ([перевод](http://citforum.ru/security/cryptography/gph/))
- в частности: [Validating other keys on your public keyring](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html) ([перевод](http://citforum.ru/security/cryptography/gph/ch03s02.shtml))
- ну и вообще про [web of trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust)

> Может я что-то делаю не так, как получить валидный ответ?

вы получили вполне валидный ответ:

1. файл подписан таким-то ключом
2. этому ключу вы (пока?) не доверяете

отличается же этот ответ от того, что приведён на сайте всего лишь потому, что у человека, его выложившего, ключ `Quicklisp Release Signing Key <release@quicklisp.org>` находится в (его) списке доверенных ключей. не более того.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение. Осталось непонятным - ЗАЧЕМ? Зачем солидный, известный программист выкладывает у себя на сайте программу/библиотеку на Lisp вместе с gpg подписью, для безусловной проверки которой не существует способа кроме моего личного доверия к ресурсу? При этом еще приводит короткую ("для тупых/ленивых") инструкцию как проверить его подпись. Инструкцию которая у меня не работает. Зачем это, что я упустил?

Comment: всё в порядке. и инструкция «работает»: вы же проверили, что файл подписан тем ключом, который опубликовал автор программы. всё отличие: он-то точно уверен, что ключ опубликован им самим, а у вас, как у не обменивавшегося с ним ключами лично и не имеющего достаточного количества промежуточных доверенных ключей (подробнее — см. ссылки, которые я привёл), сомнения должны оставаться. ну, такова она, криптографическая жизнь.